# A confusion about `ifelse`

Tags: r

There is a confusion about `ifelse`.I hope someone can help explain.
Consider code below:

```
x1 = c(1,4,3)
y1 = c(2,3,5)
# 1
> ifelse(x1 > y1, x1^2 + y1^2,y1)
[1]  2 25  5

# 2
> ifelse(x1 > y1, sum(x1),y1)
[1] 2 8 5
# from #1 I guess second element should be sum(x1) == sum(x1[2]) == sum(4)
```

Why?
Update:
After reading the book -- *The Art of R Programming*, I solve my problem.

> `ifelse(b,u,v)` where `b` is a Boolean vector, and `u` and `v` are vectors. 
>   The return value is itself a vector; element `i` is `u[i]` if `b[i]` is true, or `v[i]` if `b[i]` is false

So

```
ifelse(x1 > y1, sum(x1),y1) == ifelse(x1 > y1, c(sum(x1),sum(x1),sum(x1)),c(2,3,5))  # by recycling
# then b = c(T,F,T), u = c(8,8,8), v = c(2,3,5)
# therefore output would be (v[1],u[2],v[3]), i.e.
# [1] 2 8 5
```

Comment: No. 8 is correct. You are thinking about `ifelse(x1 > y1, sum(x1[x1 > y1]), y1)`

Answer (score 1):

`sum(x1)=8` is obvious since 1+4+3=8. Now you might wonder why `ifelse` seems to evaluate expressions differently: It is not, it is just that `^2`  cannot be applied to a vector (whats a vector squared?) so it is applying element wise. you can however apply `sum()` to a vector, which happens in the second evaluation. try `ifelse(x1 > y1, x1,y1)`